# Re-format multi dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that would like to change the format of data to use for different purpose. Example in below code there are many seasons with link & every season have year. So i would like to index these data under each year.
My current array:

```
$infoArray =array( 
                array(
                    'season'=>'winter 2014', 
                    'link'=>'link1'
                    ),
                array(
                    'season'=>'summer 2013', 
                    'link'=>'link2'
                    ),
                array(
                    'season'=>'fall 2012', 
                    'link'=>'link3'
                    ),
                array(
                    'season'=>'summer 2014', 
                    'link'=>'link4'
                    ),
                array(
                    'season'=>'winter 2013', 
                    'link'=>'link5'
                    )
            );
```

So now i want make it like below:

```
$dataArray =array( 
                '2014'=>array(
                                'winter'=>'link1', 
                                'summer'=>'link4'
                                ),
                '2013' =>array(
                                'summer'=>'link2', 
                                'winter'=>'link5'
                                ),
                '2012'=>array(
                                'fall'=>' link3', 
                                'link'=>'link3'
                                ),
                        );
```

I was just trying to find some way to solve it with my below code, but so far no luck :(

```
$newArray =array();
$innerArray=array();

foreach ($infoArray as $info){
            $season = explode(" ", $info['season']);
            $seasonName = $season[0];
            $seasonYear = $season[1];


        if (array_key_exists($seasonYear, $newArray)) {
                    $newArray[$seasonYear][$seasonName]=$info['link'] ;
            }
        else {
            $innerArray[$seasonName] = $info['link'];
            $newArray[$seasonYear]=$innerArray ;
        }

}
```

I hope somebody can point out me where i am getting wrong or if the better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is not working http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/40ac3b4d338936af42170659fc735f7e486af001

Comment: I put your code into 3v4l and it looks like it's working fine? http://3v4l.org/Auqms

Comment: in your sample desired output is wrong, since there is only one season on your `2012`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made it more complicated than it needs to be.

---

#### Example:

```
$infoArray =array(
    array(
        'season'=>'winter 2014',
        'link'=>'link1'
    ),
    array(
        'season'=>'summer 2013',
        'link'=>'link2'
    ),
    array(
        'season'=>'fall 2012',
        'link'=>'link3'
    ),
    array(
        'season'=>'summer 2014',
        'link'=>'link4'
    ),
    array(
        'season'=>'winter 2013',
        'link'=>'link5'
    )
);

foreach ($infoArray as $element) {
    list($season, $year) = explode(' ', $element['season']);
    $dataArray[$year][$season] = $element['link'];
}

var_export($dataArray);
```

---

#### Output:

```
array (
  2014 => 
  array (
    'winter' => 'link1',
    'summer' => 'link4',
  ),
  2013 => 
  array (
    'summer' => 'link2',
    'winter' => 'link5',
  ),
  2012 => 
  array (
    'fall' => 'link3',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks Paul Crovella :) Really appreciated your effort.